# trying to get text of a field in json rpc 2.0 response into ar PHP variable

Tags: json-rpc, electrum, php

I use json_decode to vardump a return which yields

array(3) { ["jsonrpc"]=> string(3) "2.0" ["result"]=> array(13) { ["status"]=> string(7) "Pending" ["amount (BTC)"]=> string(10) "0.05130899" ["index_url"]=> . . . . [more fields  here] . . .  ["address"]=> string(34) "1GHHojoC4Ai1SPMN3YoNzemLNaaj2XFHKc"

I am trying to fill a variable with the text from the "address" field and I tried

$result =  json_decode($response, true);
   $address = $result->address;

but a varbump of $addrwss is NULL

any other variant like $result->"address" or $result->["address"] is improper syntax

Can someone tell me how to get at the text of the address field of a JSON PRC 2.0 response to put it in a variable in PHP

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! You can help the site by marking answers as accepted if they are correct and address the question so that the question does not remain as "unanswered".

Answer (score 1):

To get the address you would do:

```
$result = json_decode($response, true);
$address = $result["result"]["address"];
```

Comment: Thanks.  The [0] was throwing a "undefined offset" error - so I removed it and it returns the address field now with   =>  $address = $result["result"]["address"];  <=  the var dump shows a  => string(34) <= in front of the address but I can hack the rest of the script fixed now.  I would not have figured that one out without your assistance.  Thanks - and all that come behind me to find this page thank you too.

Answer (score 1):

As you have convert response to array using json_decode so you can access by array element inside result.
You can access by echo $result["result"]["address"];